# столбец с типом данных xml

Tags: sql-server

Пытаюсь импортировать данные из файла в столбец с типом данных xml. Работаю в MS SQL Server Management Studio
Таблица содержит 2 столбца, ID с первичным ключом и xml.

```
INSERT INTO Tests(TestXML)
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(  
   BULK 'D:\12.xml',  
   SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;
```

вылетает ошибка `Массовая загрузка невозможна. Файл "D:\12.xml" не существует.`
Но такой файл есть. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: путь должен быть на сервере

Comment: ... и учётная запись, от имени которой работает сервер, должна иметь к нему доступ.

Comment: @becouse исправил на `'\\Eugene\общий доступ\12.xml'` вылетает теперь ошибка `Массовая загрузка невозможна, так как файл "\\Eugene\общий доступ\12.xml" не удалось открыть. Код ошибки операционной системы 53(Не найден сетевой путь.).`  общий доступ к папке и к файлу есть

Comment: Так в ошибке же написано, что путь  `\\Eugene\общий доступ\12.xml` невалидный. Вам надо указать точный серверный путь

Comment: на сервере = локальный файл на сервере СУБД

Comment: @VladimirAfanasyev извиняюсь, не могу понять что значит точный серверный путь, разве тот путь, который я указал не более точен?